# What happened to inbox items?

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

Inbox was going red, so I clicked on it. Then... the inbox tab came up blank!

I thought something funny was happening but couldn't file a bug report (Page Not Found errors - related?)

Here is another attempt to file the report.  A twist, at this point in time, there is finally a new item in there.  A sole lonely item.  Did a purge occur?  Are some items irrevocably lost - how will I keep track of the last several hours?

[image: empty inbox]

Answer (score 6):

There was a brief period of downtime on [Stack Auth](http://stackauth.com/) about 1/2 an hour ago.  This broke inbox loading.

During that time, new messages would still go into an inbox but older messages could not be fetched.

But if a new item *did* go into an inbox, the inbox would look "loaded" so when Stack Auth came back up the older items *still* weren't loaded.

This will fix itself automatically*, as the next time an inbox falls out of cache and is reloaded the reload will succeed (I've gone ahead and bounced your inbox for you, so old items should be showing again).

<sub>*The unread indicator will remain out of sync until checked for *some* users, but the items themselves should be fine.</sub>

Comment: My inbox is still empty. Hey Kevin, can I have my question ban uplifted? I promise to ask good questions and do the proper research before asking any questions.